# Modify scipy sparse matrix in place

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Basically, I am just trying to do a simple matrix multiplication, specifically, extract each column of it and normalize it by dividing it with its length.

```
    #csc sparse matrix
    self.__WeightMatrix__ = self.__WeightMatrix__.tocsc()
    #iterate through columns
    for Col in xrange(self.__WeightMatrix__.shape[1]):
       Column = self.__WeightMatrix__[:,Col].data
       List = [x**2 for x in Column]
       #get the column length
       Len = math.sqrt(sum(List))
       #here I assumed dot(number,Column) would do a basic scalar product
       dot((1/Len),Column)
       #now what? how do I update the original column of the matrix, everything that have been returned are copies, which drove me nuts and missed pointers so much
```

I've searched through the scipy sparse matrix documentations and got no useful information. I was hoping for a function to return a pointer/reference to the matrix so that I can directly modify its value. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `self.__WeightMatrix__[:,Col] = ...`?

Comment: I think so, the original value didn't change, leading me to believe [:Col] returned a copy, and also as far as I know, seems like csc sparse matrix doesn't support direct indexing, a error is raised if doing so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In CSC format you have two writable attributes, `data` and `indices`, which hold the non-zero entries of your matrix and the corresponding row indices. You can use these to your advantage as follows:

```
def sparse_row_normalize(sps_mat) :
    if sps_mat.format != 'csc' :
        msg = 'Can only row-normalize in place with csc format, not {0}.'
        msg = msg.format(sps_mat.format)
        raise ValueError(msg)
    row_norm = np.sqrt(np.bincount(sps_mat.indices, weights=mat.data * mat_data))
    sps_mat.data /= np.take(row_norm, sps_mat.indices)
```

To see that it actually works:

```
>>> mat = scipy.sparse.rand(4, 4, density=0.5, format='csc')
>>> mat.toarray()
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.58931687,  0.31070526],
       [ 0.24024639,  0.02767106,  0.22635696,  0.85971295],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.13613897,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.13766507,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
>>> mat.toarray() / np.sqrt(np.sum(mat.toarray()**2, axis=1))[:, None]
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.88458487,  0.46637926],
       [ 0.26076366,  0.03003419,  0.24568806,  0.93313324],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
>>> sparse_row_normalize(mat)
>>> mat.toarray()
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.88458487,  0.46637926],
       [ 0.26076366,  0.03003419,  0.24568806,  0.93313324],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

And it is also numpy fast, no Python loops spoiling the fun:

```
In [2]: mat = scipy.sparse.rand(10000, 10000, density=0.005, format='csc')

In [3]: mat
Out[3]: 
<10000x10000 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 500000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

In [4]: %timeit sparse_row_normalize(mat)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.1 ms per loop
```